# MUI Autocomplete resulting in an infinite loop of requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this Autocomplete component

```
<Autocomplete
                    filterOptions={(x) => x}
                    options={items}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                      `${option.code} - ${option.name}`
                    }
                    onInputChange={(e, value) => {
                      console.log(value);
                      setAutoComplete(value);
                    }}
                    onChange={(e, value) => {
                      //Change state of some other fields
                    }}
                    noOptionsText={false}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        {...params}
                      />
                    )}
                    value={
                      items.filter((item) => item.id == row.item_id)[0] || null
                    }
/>
```

I'm trying to make a server search and get the new `items` value, the problem is that this results in an infinite loop as when the value of the autocomplete is changed to another item, the `onInputChange` is also called, Making another request to get the new `items` value thus making changing input again and again until the server hangs up on the request.
However, this only happens when the `value` of the `Autocomplete` is controlled, I have another component that's uncontrolled and it doesn't produce this infinite loop.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this might seem weird.
But I fixed the error by setting the `setAutocomplete` to take the value of the `e?.target.value` of the `onInputchange` function, instead of the value itself. This somehow fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the reference to the selected object in `value` keeps changing.

When you download a new list of items and filter the item from the new list in the `value` prop, even though the contents of the items are identical, the new item is a different object in the browser's memory. MUI interprets it as a value change so it triggers the `onInputChange` callback, which causes new data to fetch, which causes the value to change, ... - you get an infinite loop.

Here is a CodeSandbox I prepared that demonstrates the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dawn-928gg2?file=/src/Demo.tsx

I think the easiest way to fix that would be to use the IDs of your items as options (instead of entire objects) and then find the correct item inside the `getOptionLabel` function.

IDs are strings or numbers (primitive types) so they are compared by value instead of by reference, which means that the issue will be solved. This solution will not work if your ID field is an object or an array!

That would mean changing the following props in your code:

```
options={items.map(item => item.id)}
getOptionLabel={(id) =>
  {
    const option = items.find(item => item.id === id);
    return `${option.code} - ${option.name}`;
  }
}
value={row.item_id}
```

You might also need to make changes to the `onInputChange` prop and handle `undefined`/`null` in `getOptionLabel` and `value` but it's difficult to tell exactly without seeing more of your code.

You can learn more about that issue in the documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states (see the yellow warning section)

Comment: I tried this solution but it also created the same problem, When I select anything it keeps sending the request then filtering the items then sending other requests.
I even tried to set the input to the exact value of the option so it doesn't change but it kept changing. I think I need to change the approach itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly by "I even tried to set the input to the exact value". I have just checked and it seems like the issue is gone when the label (return value of `getOptionLabel`) does not change. See the updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-dawn-928gg2?file=/src/Demo.tsx (line 30)